# Listen to events outside of template, but only when the template is present

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I use IronRouter to structure my app into controllers (routers), on which I started attaching my events. So far so good.

I then started using the `{{#contentFor ...}}` feature and since then, my events don't fire anymore, because the region I render the relevant element, is part of a different DOM tree.

Is there any approach to still listen to these events? I considered simply adding a global listener, but that would remove a lot of flexibility from the events.

*CoffeeScript:*

```
MyRouter = RouteController.extend(...)
MyRouter.events(
  'click .inside': (event) ->
     alert("inside") # works
  'click .outside': (event) ->
     alert("outside") # does not work
)
```

*HTML:*

```
<button type="button" class="inside">
   inside
</button>

{{#contentFor 'anotherDomRegion'}}
  <button type="button" class="outside">
    outside
  </button>
{{/contentFor}}
```

*And layout file:*

```
<h1>event demo</h1>
<div>
  {{> yield}}
</div>
<div>
  {{> yield 'anotherDomRegion'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem myself. The only way I've been able to work around it is to set the contentFor to a template so you can assign your events to that template.

```
{{> contentFor region="anotherDomRegion" template="anotherDomRegion"}}
```

then;

```
<template name="anotherDomRegion"> ... </template>
```

and;

```
Template.anotherDomRegion.events({ ... });
```

Good luck!